# Agenda page listing last 6 posts, grouped by month(dsc)

Tags: wordpress, class, posts

Could I use some help? I'm worse than a rookie with PHP stuff.

I'm trying to create a loop that requests posts from an specific category(agenda). I'd need 6 posts from an specific month stacked in 2 rows by 3 columns, something like the image down below.

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/833/schemeq.jpg

I was trying to merge codes and make this work, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be great.

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php for ($i=1; i<12; $i++)
{
    $month=$i;
    $nQuery = new WP_Query("monthnum=$month&order=DSC&posts_per_page=6" );
    if (nQuery->have_posts()) : while (nQuery->have_posts()) : nQuery->the_post();

<div class="box<?php if( $count%3 == 0 ) { echo "'-1'; }; $count++; ?> post">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="alignleft" > 
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('postfeatured'); } else { ?> <img src="/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/thumb_featured.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    <?php } ?> </a>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?>
                <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0', 'twentyten' ), __( '1', 'twentyten' ), __( '%', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></span>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            <h2><span class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span></h2>
            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
</div>
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What results are you getting now?  Quite simply, you could handle the columns with CSS.  Also, I do not see a `cat` argument in you query.

Comment: It says there is an error on the line:

if (nQuery->have_posts()) : while (nQuery->have_posts()) : nQuery->the_post();